# How to add custom prerequisite for ClickOnce?

Tags: wpf, clickonce, prerequisites

I have a WPF application which is distributed by ClickOnce. ClickOnce handles well prerequisite like LocalDb and .Net Desktop Runtime. I started to use Identity in the program so now I need ASP.NET Core Runtime as well, but it is not in the list.
I have sent the problem to MS 3 weeks ago, but no response from them.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ClickOnce-prerequisite-ASPNET-Core-Run/10179285?

I started to look how to add a custom prerequisite but the descriptions was quite old or not detailed. Does somebody have a good description?

UPDATE 1

I did some research.

1. On windows 10 my Bootstrap directory is at `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages"`. But here are only some of the prerequisite, for example `SqlLocalDB2019` but not `net 5`. Why is that?
2. I have found some useful stuff, an [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435960/clickonce-wpf-application-with-custom-and-default-prerequisites) and a [new](https://foxlearn.com/articles/adding-custom-prerequisites-to-visual-studio-setup-project-468.html). They provided the `product.xml` and the `en/package.xml`. I have copied the files to the `Packages` folder but the new prerequisites did not show in VS. I also tried to copy and modify slightly the existing `SqlLocalDB2019` folder but the new version did not show either. What am I missing?
3. What changes do I need in the two files once the prerequisite appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are two location for prerequisites

   - "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages"
   - "d:\Program Files\Visual Studio 2022 Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\BootstrapperPackages"
2. I did not found the problem the old examples but I was able to add my own prerequisite.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74536380/5852947